# My "yum update" is not working

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

I am having problem with "yum update"
This is the output:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock: (28, 'connect() timed out!')    
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

How can I solve this? I tried editing my resolv.conf, but It  didn't work.
Thank you.
I use wifi and my OS is Centos 6

Comment: do you have a working internet connection? for example, does `ping google.com` work? you tell us you edited /etc/resolv.conf but not what was and what you modified.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have a working internet connection. In the posts I read, they instructed to add this nameserver 8.8.8.8 . Then, I restarted my PC, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Where are you located in the world? What is your Internet connection? Is it wifi or cable? Please add it to the post. Add also the output of `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`

Comment: This kind of errors happen occasionally when the Internet connection is flaky, or perhaps during maintenance/update of the mirror. Try again, after making sure your network is fine.

Comment: hi @vonbrand , our internet is fine. And this has been my problem for weeks, I cant install anything because of this. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: @MagentoUser, check `/etc/yum.conf` and `/etc/yum.repos.d`. The later should contain the URLs, something like `baseurl=...` and `metalink=...`. Copy the files to a safe location, and uncomment the `baseurl` line, comment out the `metalink` one for all repos, and try again. That way you are bypassing the mirror mechanism, and hitting the official upstream directly. Do revert back afterwards, if the problem persists, it might be your nearest mirror is just offline/broken/not a mirror anymore. You might want to bring it up *with full details* with the CentOS folks.

Comment: I did already but its still producing the error. I wonder if its just offline, because its been like this for weeks! If there's no mirror anymore, what should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Clear yum cache, `yum clean all`, followed by `yum makecache` to refresh it.

If this doesn't help, get a new CentOS repository definition file from the official website. Given you are using version 6, it has been a while since you installed it, and the repository definitions in `/etc/yum.repos.d` might be pointing to the wrong location to obtain the mirror list.

Comment: When I do "yum makecache" it produces the same error.

Comment: Look at this [CentOS repository page](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) and make sure your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` contains URLs that are resolvable and reachable from where you are.
Also, look at the list of mirrors returned by [this URL](http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os) - these are the mirrors closest to you. If none of them is reachable, try using a free proxy somewhere to force a different list of mirrors.